# example of a sequence of random variables to be increasing? (continuation)

Tags: sequences-and-series, random-variables

An increasing sequence of random variable mean that for every $w$ the following hold: $$X_1(w)\le X_2(w) \le X_3(w)...$$
What I wanted to understand is this definition with a practical example. 
My intuition was that:

$X_1$ could be thought as the function that for $w$ (as for example the results of the throwing of a dice) take the value of the number appeared on the dice.

$X_2$, instead, to the event throw of a dice take the value of the number of the face $+ 1$.

$X_3$, instead, the number of the face $+ 2$.

And so on.. is it correct this intuition?
Could someone do another, more practical, example of increasing r.v.?

This post could be the conclusion of the following question: [What does it mean for a sequence of random variables to be increasing?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1658792/what-does-it-mean-for-a-sequence-of-random-variables-to-be-increasing/1992768)

Comment: How about $X_2$ as the sum of the numbers oh two dice and $X_3$ the sum of numbers of three dice,.

Comment: Let $X_n$ be the number of $6$s rolled in the first $n$ rolls.

Comment: @herbsteinberg in that case could not be that $X_1=6$ and $X_2=4$ (e.g. 2+2)? then it is true that it is increasing?

Comment: another question: so the r.v. in a sequence could they don't share the domain space? e.g. : could it be that $X_1$ is the number of a dice, and $X_2$ the number of tail flipping a coin?

Comment: @Alberto  What I meant was  - toss three dice and get $6,4,1$.  Then $X_1=6$, $X_2=10$, and $X_3=11$.